# How to insert a svg into a hml table which spans over multiple rows

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to insert an svg-image in a html-table that should span over multiple rows of that table. How do I do that?

Here's what I have now:

[image]

But I want to produce something like this:

[image]

My svg-rects should span per one table-column over multiple rows:

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

body {
     position: absolute;
}

svg {
    stroke:rgb(0,0,0);
    stroke-width:2;
    border:1px solid black;
    position:abolsute;
    z-index:10;
}

svg > rect.firstrect {
    fill: rgb(234,145,234);
    stroke:#006600;
}

svg > rect.secondrect {
    fill: rgb(123,11,234);
    stroke:#006600;
}

svg > rect.thirdrect {
    fill: rgb(11,234,98);
    stroke:#006600;
}

table {
    border:1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    width:55%;
    height:55%;
    margin-top:10px;
    z-index:20;
}

td,th {
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:2px;
    width:250px;
    height:25px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}

td.withsvg{
    position: relative;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<table>
    <tr>
        <th >23.04</th>
        <th>24.04</th>
        <th>ProfilNr</th>
        <th>Schnitt</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>03:37</td>
        <td>11:35</td>
        <td>19:13</td>
        <td>21:46</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='withsvg'>
        <!--    <svg width="250px" height="250px">
                <rect class='firstrect' x="0" y="100" height="150" width="100%"/>
                <rect class='secondrect' x="25" y="150" height="100" width="80%"/>
                <rect class='thirdrect' x="50" y="200" height="50" width="60%"/>
            </svg> -->
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>


</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a <div> to be able to interact with your row size.

Sadly it makes the code more complicated but you have to use this kind of syntax :

```
<td class='withsvg'>
      <div class="content">
        <svg>
            <rect class='firstrect' x="0" y="0" height="50" width="100%"/>
            <rect class='secondrect' x="35" y="3" height="150" width="50%"/>
            <rect class='thirdrect' x="43" y="6" height="120" width="40%"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </td>
```

The code is the same as yours, i just added a <div> around your <rect>.

Here is the example : [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j8Luzcrc/1/)

Comment: can you give me a more detailed example ?

Comment: I need a better understanding of your question. On your result picture did you make 2 examples or does the first rect need to be split into two differents columns ? If it's not splitting, where did the 3rd rect go ? You fixed the width of them in your first example and in your result pictures they have a different width. Do they have to adapt to the cell width ? A color code would have been better between the code and the result to understand your question.

Comment: yeah that are two examples: there should be also a third rect in each column too, but i forgot to draw....the width of the first rect should be the width of the cell or the column, the second rect should be half the width of the first and the third half of the second etc.

Comment: is this what you want ? [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j8Luzcrc/) I put the width in % as you told me in your last comment, and let the height of your rect in px believing you want it fixed that way.

Comment: sorry for the confusion - ive edited the color code of the second image so that hopefully it is more clear what I want...

Comment: Well i dont see what's stopping you now. I finished the CSS so it looks exactly like your result, but i think you could have done it, because the method was already there :) [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j8Luzcrc/1/)